# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/dolphins-MBP.pid)

Tags: macos, mysql

Today when I changed the mysql bind address in MacOS 13.4.1 from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0:

```
/usr/local/etc ⌚ 21:14:53
$ cat my.cnf                                                                                                                                                      ‹ruby-2.7.2›
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

then start the mysql shows error:

```
/usr/local/etc ⌚ 21:14:20
$ sudo mysql.server start                                                                                                                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›

Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/dolphins-MBP.err'.
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/dolphins-MBP.pid).
(base)
```

I have already tried to change the folder permission like this:

```
/usr/local/etc ⌚ 21:12:18
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/                                                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›
(base)
```

still could not fixed this issue.

Comment: What would changing the permissions on the folder accomplish?  What did the server write to the log file?